# Unexpected answer for 0-1 knapsack

Tags: c++, algorithm

My code for 0-1 knapsack:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int max(int a,int b)
{
    return a>b?a:b;
}
int main()
{
    string s;
    int N,W;

    getline(cin,s);
    stringstream(s)>>N>>W;

    cout<<"Enter value and weight of item\n";
    int v[N+1],w[N+1];

    for(int i=1;i<=N;i++)
    {
        getline(cin,s);
        stringstream(s)>>v[i]>>w[i];
    }
    int max_val[N+1][W+1];
    for(int i=0;i<=W;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=N;j++)
        {
            if(i==0 || j==0)
            {
                max_val[i][j]=0;
            }
            else
            {
                max_val[i][j]=max_val[i][j-1];
                if(w[j]<=i)
                {
                    max_val[i][j]=max(max_val[i][j],max_val[i-w[j]][j-1]+v[j]);
                }
            }
            cout<<max_val[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<max_val[W][N];
}
```

Input:

```
3 5  
60 1  
100 2  
120 3
```

max_val:

```
0 0 0 0   
0 60 60 60   
0 60 100 100   
0 60 160 160   
0 60 160 180   
0 60 160 160
```

The output is 160 but the expected output is 220.
The value matrix is 60,100,120 and weight is 1,2,3.
When I debugged the value of weight matrix was changed during i=5 which gave the wrong answer.
Can anyone tell me why is the weight matrix getting modified?

Comment: Indent your code. It usually helps you find your own errors.

Comment: Just a debugging advise: write a function which prints whole `max_val` matrix and use it after each change. So you will see how data evolves.

Answer (score 3):

You have defined your `max_val` array as `int max_val[N+1][W+1]`, so the first index is the number of item, and the second is weight. However, you use the indices in the opposite order: `max_val[i][j]` with `i` being weight and `j` the item number.

Therefore your writes to `max_val` are sometimes out-of-bound, and anything can happen. The simplest way to fix this is to change `max_val` declaration to `int max_val[W+1][N+1]`.